# How to make screen reader reads a list?

Tags: javascript, html, screen-readers

I would like to use the screen reader for accessibility purpose in order to read the text in a list, I found out some example on the web that make it work when the items of `<li>` wrapped with `<a>`.

I tried something like the following but it doesn't work:

```
<ul role="list">
  <li role="listitem">
    <div><h3 aria-label="item 1">item 1</h3></div>
  </li>
  <li role="listitem">
    <div><h3 aria-label="item 2">item 2</h3></div>
  </li>
  <li role="listitem">
    <div><h3 aria-label="item 2">item 3</h3></div>
  </li>
  <li role="listitem">
    <div><h3 aria-label="item 4">itwem 4</h3></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Hope you can help me with that.

Comment: Your markup looks fine to me - what happens exactly? What screen-reader software are you using? What happens when you run it, exactly?

Comment: I use MacOS voice over, it select the first item of the list but doesn't read it or any of the items.

Answer (score 10):

The [#1 rule for using ARIA](https://www.w3.org/TR/using-aria/#rule1) (both `aria-*` attributes and the `role` attribute) is to **not** use it if you don't have to.  Your code sample, while valid, has too much aria, all of it superfluous.

A `<ul>` has a role=list by default and the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html53/grouping-content.html#ref-for-allowed-aria-role-attribute-values%E2%91%A1%E2%91%A0) specifically says not to set the role.

Same with the [`<li>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html53/grouping-content.html#ref-for-allowed-aria-role-attribute-values%E2%91%A1%E2%91%A1) element.

The accessible name for your headings (`<h3>`) will come from the text content of the heading, according to step 2F of the "[Accessible Name and Description Computation](https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.1/#step2)", so having an `aria-label` for the `<h3>` is not necessary.

So, your code sample is **exactly** the same as this code snippet:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>
      <h3>item 1</h3>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <h3>item 2</h3>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <h3>item 3</h3>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <h3>item 4</h3>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Lists, in general, are not keyboard focusable so you won't navigate to them with the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key.  I think that's why you mentioned wrapping the list item in an anchor tag, `<a>`, to allow you to <kbd>TAB</kbd> to the link.

The way a screen reader user will navigate to a list is with shortcut keys.  Both JAWS and NVDA use the <kbd>L</kbd> key to navigate to a list and the <kbd>I</kbd> ('eye') key to navigate to a list item.  A screen reader user can also walk the DOM using the up/down arrow keys.  VoiceOver users on iOS devices can set their rotor to "Lists" and can then swipe up/down to the next list.

So, if you are trying to force lists to be focusable using the keyboard, you would be doing a screen reader user a disservice because they're not used to navigating to a list in that manner.  Non-interactive elements (such as `<ul>` or `<p>` or `<h3>`) should not be keyboard focusable.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I removed the extra aria-* and roles, but I couldn't make the screen reader read out the list items.

Comment: tell me what keys you're using in the screen reader to get to the list (and which screen reader you're testing)